# Is it possible to log specific resason for Network Error for failed HTTP in browser(Chrome)

Tags: reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest

Using React JS for web dev with axios library i'm making request to backend. It works fine during testing but when i connected it to Rollbar I see that for some users in production it returns 500 Network error

It is substantial amount of users and refresh doesn't help them.
I'm trying to narrow issue down to specific 'timeout' 'firewall' etc. but it doesn't look like axios has this in error object.

Is there any way to tell in browser why **specifically** there is a Network Error?